# How to show radio button after selecting option

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have a form with several inputs like below

[image]

This is the value from Jenis Layanan

[image: jenis layanan]

When I choose value from Jenis Layanan, if I choose Corporate, I want to add new field radio button below jenis layanan. And if I choose Perorangan or Home Visit, radio button dissapear.

How can I make it work like this?

### My code

```html
      <div class="p-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label font-weight-bold" for="sub_product">Jenis Layanan</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="sub_product" id="sub_product">
            <option value="1">Perorangan</option>
            <option value="2">Home Visit</option>
            <option value="3">Corporate</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="p-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label font-weight-bold" for="appoinment_date">Tanggal Pelayanan</label>
          <input name="appointment_date" placeholder="Tanggal Layanan" id="appointment_date" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write some JS to your form with event listener:

```
document.querySelector('#sub_product').addEventListener('change', () => {
// your code
})
```

I made codepen for you with an example:

https://codepen.io/VeterJS/pen/BaRvYYx

Comment: Thankyou @Veter ! And for improvment, I insert style="display: none;" on radio button, so when page reload, radio button dissapear first.

Answer (score 0):

Is easier with jQuery, when the **Corporate** option is selected the div `display` containing the radio buttons is changed to `block` and when other option is selected then the display goes back to `none` which hides the element.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    
    let option = '';
    
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      option = $( this ).text();
    });
    
    if(option == 'Corporate'){
      $('#radioBTNS').css('display','block')
    }else{
      $('#radioBTNS').css('display','none')
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="p-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label font-weight-bold" for="sub_product">Jenis Layanan</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="sub_product" id="sub_product">
      <option value="1">Perorangan</option>
      <option value="2">Home Visit</option>
      <option value="3">Corporate</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="radioBTNS" style="margin:10px;display:none">
  <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30">
  <label for="age1">Radio btn one</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="60">
  <label for="age2">Radio btn two</label><br>  
</div>

<div class="p-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label font-weight-bold" for="appoinment_date">Tanggal Pelayanan</label>
    <input name="appointment_date" placeholder="Tanggal Layanan" id="appointment_date" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
```